# jquery background resize

Tags: jquery, background, resize, refresh

For some reason this does not run correctly if the page is refreshed. Works fine otherwise. The id.background is on the body tag.

```
    var theWindow = $(window),
      $bg = $("#background"),
      aspectRatio = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

    function resizeBg() {
      if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
        $bg.removeClass()
           .addClass('bgheight');
      } else {
        $bg.removeClass()
           .addClass('bgwidth');
      }
    }

    theWindow.resize(function() {
      resizeBg();
    }).trigger("resize");
```

Comment: Are you triggering the resize in the document ready event? e.g., `$( document ).ready( function() { theWindow.trigger( 'resize' ); } );`

Comment: Yeah, prob should have added that.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at this plugin, i've used it a few times.

http://bavotasan.com/2011/full-sizebackground-image-jquery-plugin/

Do you have the code you wrote inside a `$('document').ready(function(){});` ?

Comment: Yeah, prob should have added that. I'll check out the link, thanks.

Comment: Consider trying 'window' as well

Comment: @mkprogramming - the OP is assigning $( window ) to theWindow. If you're thinking `$( window ).ready()` would be helpful, it wouldn't be - window throws an onload event

Comment: Thanks, didn't catch that part. Did adding the $('document').ready() help?